# How to add quotes to the src attribute of the img tag

Tags: php, html, regex

I have correct several posts on a database that look like these:

```
<a href="somelink.html"><img src=someimage.jpg border=1 alt="some text"></a>
```

So I need to:

- remove the border=1 attribute (str_replace will do the job)
- add quotes at the begin and end of the src attribute: src="someimage.jpg"
- close the img tag with adding /> at the end of the tag

One thing I tried is to parse the dom and get the SRC source:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
    $body = $this->removeUnnecessaryTags($body);
    $doc->loadHTML($this->removeUnnecessaryTags($body));
    $imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
        $result[] = [ 'src' => $tag->getAttribute('src'), 'alt' => $tag->getAttribute('alt') ];
    }
```

I know this can be done with regex but my regex knowledge is not very good. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's unlikely someone would do the entire job for you.

Comment: right :) I updated the question, basically I've parse the dom document

Comment: Wait now, you have that HTML in a database? Why? And you want to fix it when using it on the client side, not fix it in the database?

Comment: @Alex: nothing forbids to update the database with the well formatted html after.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You are right, I reacted on _parse the dom document_ and got some misaligned associations. Still, the major question is why OP stores html in a database like this.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explained my self correctly. I'm fixing the contents in the database so I need to add the quotes to img tags. Casimir solution worked great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to use DOMDocument features and libxml options:

```
$html = '<a href="somelink.html"><img src=someimage.jpg border=1 alt="some text"></a>';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

$result = $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);

echo $result;
```

`LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` prevents to add automatically a DTD when the DTD is missing.
`LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` prevents to add html and body tags when missing.

The saveXML method will save your document with an XML compliant syntax, so it solves the self-closing tags problem.
`$dom->documentElement` is used as parameter to avoid the xml declaration that is automatically added.(*)

Whatever the method you use (saveXML or saveHTML) double quotes are used to enclose attributes automatically.

(*) This will remove an eventual DTD too, so if you want to preserve it, you can use this workaround to remove the xml declaration:

```
$result = $dom->saveXML();
$result = substr($result, strpos($result, "\n") + 1);
```